# Laravel Query Builder - Use sum method on a generated attribute

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Let's say I have these 2 models:

**Order Model:**

- id
- state (incomplete, complete)

---

**Item Model:**

- id
- order_id
- type
- is_worthy.

.

```
/**
 * Returns the item's price according to its worthy
 */
public function getPriceAttribute()
{
    return $this->is_worthy ? 100 : 10; // $
}
```

---

So far so good.

Now I want to summarize the price of the complete orders. So I'm doing this:

```
App\Item::whereHas('order', function ($query) {
    $query->where('state', 'complete');
})->sum('price')
```

But the thing is, that I don't have in my `items` table the column `price`. Because the `price` attribute is generated in the Model.

So my question is, how can I summarize price of the complete orders?

Comment: Does Laravel have a whereType? What is the error message?

Comment: @FatimahSanni Laravel has dynamic where methods like whereXyz (xyz being a column name of the table)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this:

**1. Have PHP do all the work**

```
$items = App\Item::whereHas('order', function ($query) {
    $query->where('state', 'complete');
})->get();
$sum = $items->sum(function($item) {
    return $item->price;
});
// In Laravel 5.4, you can replace the last line with $sum = $items->sum->price;
```

**2. Have SQL do all the work**

```
$items = App\Item::whereHas('order', function ($query) {
    $query->where('state', 'complete');
})->select('*', DB::raw('IF(is_worthy, 100, 10) as price'))->sum('price');
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel

model

```
/**
 * Returns the item's price according to its worthy
 */
public function getPriceAttribute()
{
    return $this->is_worthy ? 100 : 10; // $
}
```

controller

```
retrun OrderItem::where('state', 'complete')->get()->sum('price');
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.