# Laravel - How to sum on relationship across model (i.e. not on record by record level)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

**Performance optimization**

For performance reasons I do not want to use eloquent to produce a collection. I'd rather let SQL do the heavy lifting and calculate the total number of powers of attorney signed across all claims which meet certain criteria, to avoid looping PHP on each claim record (e.g. via withCount etc.)

**I want to do something simple like this:**

```
Claim::join('powers_of_attorney', 'powers_of_attorney.claim_id', '=', 'claims.id')->selectRaw(['claims.id', 'count(case when powers_of_attorney.status = "closed" and powers_of_attorney.claim_id = claims.id and powers_of_attorney.deleted_at is null then powers_of_attorney.id end) as poasSigned'])->sum('poasSigned');
```

Should work according to this:
[Laravel Query Builder - Use sum method on a generated attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537560/laravel-query-builder-use-sum-method-on-a-generated-attribute/42538018#42538018)

**But I get error message**

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'poasSigned' in 'field list' (SQL: select sum(`poasSigned`) as aggregate from `claims` inner join `powers_of_attorney` on `powers_of_attorney`.`claim_id` = `claims`.`id` where `claims`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

Ideas on how to solve?

**Claim model**

```
id
name
...
```

**Powers of attorney model**

```
id
claim_id
status
...
```

Comment: I think the argument you pass to `selectRaw` should be a `string` instead of an `array`?

Comment: @ChinLeung: Even if I make the selectRaw a string I get thet same error message :(

Comment: Did you change `'claims.id, count(...)'` into a single string or did you pass 2 parameters?

Comment: @ChinLeung: Passed two parameters (each string). But to make a simpler example we can use this: Claim::select('*', DB::raw('IF(claim_filed, 1, 0) as price'))->sum('price'); Still does not allow suming on the calculated field (in this case price). Really don't know why... :/

Comment: Try to pass the select as a single string like in my example, `'claims.id, count(...)'`.

Comment: @ChinLeung: Same problem :(

$result = Claim::select('*, DB::raw("IF(claim_filed, 1, 0) as price"')->sum('price');

Even if try this, it still does not recognize the "sum" column:
$result = Claim::selectRaw("IF(claim_filed, 1, 0) as price")->sum('price');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194444/discussion-between-peder-wessel-and-chin-leung).

Comment: You need to move the `poasSigned` column to the `sum()` clause and remove `selectRaw()`: `[...]->sum(B::raw('count(case when powers_of_attorney.status = "closed" and powers_of_attorney.claim_id = claims.id and powers_of_attorney.deleted_at is null then powers_of_attorney.id end)'));`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir: Not sure I follow. Do you mind typing out the proposed query and I'll test it?

Comment: You want to get a single sum for all rows, right? `Claim::join('powers_of_attorney', 'powers_of_attorney.claim_id', '=', 'claims.id')->sum(DB::raw('count(case when powers_of_attorney.status = "closed" and powers_of_attorney.claim_id = claims.id and powers_of_attorney.deleted_at is null then powers_of_attorney.id end)'));`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir thanks. Now it throws an error:

"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function (SQL: select sum(count(case when powers_of_attorney.status = "closed" and powers_of_attorney.claim_id = claims.id and powers_of_attorney.deleted_at is null then powers_of_attorney.id end)) as aggregate from `claims` inner join `powers_of_attorney` on `powers_of_attorney`.`claim_id` = `claims`.`id` where `claims`.`deleted_at` is null)".

Presume it has to do with Laravel and strict querying, and not the actual query you sent me?

Comment: Can you describe in a sentence what the query should do?